# Matlab *.p file run from within R

Tags: r, matlab

Using R.Matlab or another tool, is there a way to run a Matlab pre-parsed psuedocode file (*.p) from within R.  All input data files accessed by this pre-parsed *.p are asci (.csv), located in the directory from which R would be started.  There is also a fixed-name parameter file (text file) that is read or asked for.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible. MATLAB `*.p` files are encoded / encrypted files that can only be run in the MATLAB environment. There is also no way to convert them back to a regular MATLAB file (`*.m`). Not sure where you got the name: `"pre-parsed psuedocode file"` from, a `*.p` file is formally called a "protected function file".

Comment: Very helpful information - exactly all that I needed to know!  I'm waiting to accept this or the second answer (codegen to create c code) until I am able to try it, or here further from others who have done so.

Answer (score 4):

You might have some options if you have access to matlab.

1. If you got matlab on your machine you could use the COM interface to start the p-file in matlab and then obtain the results.
2. If you got access on a remote machine. It seems with codegen you can create c code from the p file. Suppose you can even build a library using mbuild. these should run flawless.

Comment: I don't have matlab on my machine but do have remote access.  Thanks for ideas on 2.  I'm not in a position to try them currently but hope to with the next year.